# Mongodb Query: Query by nested value with unknown parent

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The records in my database are structured like:

```
{"_id": "1", children: {"bOb": {age: 5}, "SallY": {age: 10}}}
{"_id": "2", children: {"JeFF": {age: 8}, "BilL": {age: 4}}}
```

I am looking for a query that will allow me to find a document that contains an age for a particular child. For an example, if I pass "4" as a parameter, I expect the following result:

```
{"_id": "2", children: {"JeFF": {age: 8}, "BilL": {age: 4}}}
```

Unfortunately, it is out of the scope of my project to restructure the entire schema that was dumped upon me. I appreciate any insight

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$where` operator to find your records. This operator is not fast, but will return the records you are after. It uses a JavaScript function to iterate over the keys in your children object and checks if the age for that key matches.

```
 db.data.find({
   $where: function() {
     for (var key in this.children)  {
       if (this.children[key].age ===4){
       return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
   }
 })
```